# Angular $routeProvider override-able fallback routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

I'm creating my first sizable angular project, so I've opted to break out my angular application code into directories like so:

```
app/
    calendar/
        calendar.js
    contacts/
        contacts.js
    companies/
        companies.js    
    ...
    app.js
```

Each of these directories will include a handful of files for views (.html), directives, services, etc.

In my `app.js` file, I want to setup default routes that will be used maybe 80% of the time, like this:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/:page', {
        templateUrl: function($routeParams) {
            return 'app/' + $routeParams.page + '/index.html';
        },
        controller: 'PageController'
    })
```

However, I want the ability to "override" that route from within my modules so I can do things like swap out the controller, do dependency injection stuff, and so on. I would like that sort of logic contained within the module itself to keep things...well...modular, so I would rather not define each module's routing logic within `app.js`. So for example, in my `app/calendar/calendar.js` file I want to say:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/calendar', {
        templateUrl: 'app/calendar/index.html',
        controller: 'CalendarIndexController', 
        resolve: { ... }
    })
```

The problem is that the definition in `app.js` is matched against the location first, so this calendar route is never used.

To achieve this, right now I'm just including an extra file after all of my module javascript files that sets up my fallback routes last, but this seems a little clunky. Is there anyway to define the routes within `app.js` so that they are override-able?

Comment: probably need to look into using ui-router

Comment: @Divey did you ever figure this out ?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray I just dealt with it by defining my fallback routes last, after all other routes were defined. Eventually I ended up biting the bullet and switching the entire app to use ui-router. It was a bit painful at first, but worth it in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to adapt this technique for dynamically loading controllers described by Dan Wahlin here http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs  combined with your default routes where the parameter controls which view to load. You could pass the same page parameter to the resolve function to control which combination of view and controller to serve up?